# Selenium-RC PHP example fails

Tags: php, selenium-rc

I'm trying to get Selenium-RC to work in a Windows/XAMPP environment. I'm coding in PHP.

The following command line opens two Firefox windows.

java -jar jar\selenium-server-1.0.3\selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox"  "http://www.google.com" "jar\selenium-php-client-driver-1.0.1\TestSuite.php" "logs\TestSuite-F.html"

The first Firefox window opens http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/TestRunner-splash.html?start=true

The second Firefox window opens chrome://src/content/TestRunner.html?auto=true&multiWindow=true&defaultLogLevel=info&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&resultsUrl=http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/postResults&test=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4444%2Fselenium-server%2Ftests%2FTestSuite.php

The top left frame of this second window contains:

```
addTestSuite('SeleniumTest'); 
$suite->addTestSuite('GoogleTest'); 
$suite->addTestSuite('MockBrowserTest'); 
return $suite; } } 
if (PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD == 'Framework_AllTests::main') { 
    Framework_AllTests::main(); 
} ?>
```

This would appear to be wrong and there is no way to actually run the test.

Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.